# Conditional value for a #define

Tags: macros, c-preprocessor

I want to define a macro kDependentMacro to be 38 if the macro kIndependentMacro is defined and 40 otherwise.  What is the simplest way to do that?

Comment: yes.  And they should allow this comment without the second sentence.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
#ifdef kIndependentMacro
#  define kDependentMacro 38
#else
#  define kDependentMacro 40
#endif
```

Comment: ugh.  I was hoping there was something prettier.  Judging by the fact that this already has 4 upvotes, apparently not :(