# Conditional macro #define for a function - causing: "function" redefined warning

Tags: gcc, macros, c-preprocessor

I just saw this thread, describing how to add conditional macros:
[Conditional value for a #define](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3041300/conditional-value-for-a-define)

but in my case I am defining a function within the condition.

```
#if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR

#define doSomething(){\
    \\ does something
}\

#else

#define doSomething(){\
    \\ does something else
}\

#endif
```

This does work, except I is causing gcc compiler to throw this warning:

```
"doSomething" redefined
This is the location of the previous arguments
```

Is there any workaround to help getting rid of the warnings?

**UPDATE:**

So I tried including the condition inside my definition:

```
#define doSomething(){\

#if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
    \\ do something
#else 
    \\ do something else
#endif

}\
```

but that throws an error:

```
error: '#' is not followed by a macro parameter.
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found the answer to my question [here](http://bytes.com/topic/c/answers/472611-possible-write-such-macro).

**Conclusion:** 
you *cannot* include #ifdef etc... inside #define, because there should only be one pre-processing directive per line.

So although we can break the line with a backslash '\' this helps writing readable multiline macros,
but the preprocessor will see it as one line:

```
#define doSomething(){ #if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR ... #endif }
```

Which throws this error:

```
error: '#' is not followed by a macro parameter.
```

That makes sense, so I will have to rethink my implementation.

Answer (score 2):

Also, this might address the error you received:
`#` and `##` have special purposes inside macro definitions. `#` is used to surround a macro parameter with double quotes. `##` is used to concatenate two macro parameters. Example:
`#define ABC(X) #X`
`ABC(hello)` results in `"hello"`.
`#define XYZ(X,Y) X##Y`
`XYZ(O,K)` results in `OK`.
Note that this feature is (possibly) unique to ANSI C.
Also, why would you be using a macro like this? Might a function work better for you?

Comment: "Also, why would you be using a macro like this?"
Yeah exactly, poor logic at the time and made me rethink the purpose and  implementation.

Answer (score 1):

There is a quirk in your thinking which is by analogy/ extension. doSomething() has to be viewed as a function-like macro. As such its definition is ambivalent. Zoom out and see below:

```
doSomething() {
#if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
   // conditionally compiled code
#else
   // platform-specific code
#endif
}
```

Comment: you're forgetting that doSomething is a defined macro. If i have #define doSomething() #if ... this will break the macro and you'll get the error: '#' is not followed by a macro parameter.

Answer (score 0):

One option to consider is creating a condition in a macro that will resolve at compile time.  Consider the following:

If I would like to call a different function based on the value of 'c' as a pre-processor action, I can define a macro that checks the value of 'c' statically.

```
#define AorB(c) ((c>0) ? (Do_A(c)) : (Do_B(c)))
```

Then if you configure a level of optimization that removes branches that are never reachable, it should strip out which ever case wasn't performed.  This may not exactly be what you were looking for.